# How to fix the slant of bathroom floor

Tags: shower, tile, drain, drainage, caulking

This is a follow up question to [How long does caulk need to dry in a 1" gap?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90654/how-long-does-caulk-need-to-dry-in-a-1-gap)

Some additional background information is that this is in China and bathrooms are not designed for contained bathtubs/showers but generally slant all the floor tiles towards a single drain. Many households have no shower stall and allow shower water to spray everywhere in the bathroom. After a shower they mop or squeegee the water towards the drain.

We have a glass shower stall but because of the slope of the floor it doesn't lie flat. There is a large gap on one side where the floor slants to allow water from the entire bathroom to flow towards the drain. I've been having trouble keeping the shower water from washing away the caulk placed over this gap (see previous question for a picture and details).

I'm pretty sure now that the solution is to fix the floor slope so that water doesn't pool up and wash away the caulk. How should I do that?

Here's a picture of the water pooling area:
 [image: water pooling area]

Comment: Yes, there is a drainage problem. So I'm asking how to fix that before reapplying caulk. The slope of the bathroom floor goes down to the drain. That is, the whole bathroom floor is sloped. So when the shower stall was put in it blocked the flow of water outside and inside. So if we spilled water outside the shower (like a toilet overflow) it piles up outside the shower. And when we take a shower the water inside also piles up inside because the slope is not perfect.

Comment: Is it possible to get any pictures of the bathroom in question?

Comment: @bigbull15 I've added a picture

Comment: I can add this as answer if you want, but the only way I can see that you can resolve your problem is to remove the tiles and possibly the shower and add to the subfloor changing the slope.

Comment: @bigbull15 if that's the case, can you link to a thorough guide or reference on how to do it?